# Error creating from json using ngformly in Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-formly

I'm using Angular 5 to create forms using the ng-formly library, and I am stuck on this error below. I used their example online, but can't see why there is an issue in their core project when used in my project.

```
OrderComponent.html:33 ERROR TypeError: Cannot add property model, object is not extensible
    at eval (ngx-formly-core.js:90)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at assignModelToFields (ngx-formly-core.js:86)
    at FormlyFormBuilder.buildForm (ngx-formly-core.js:503)
    at FormlyForm.ngOnChanges (ngx-formly-core.js:825)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:12407)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:13935)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:13878)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:14771)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:14712)
```

Any idea why I'm getting this error message?

Comment: Can you add your code to the question pointing out the error?

Comment: The error occurs in the OrderComponent.html. Please provide its code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I had the binding setup wrong on my form in the html. Instead of [model]="model", I had (model)="model". Issue is resolved.